# Dynamically creating variable using string

Tags: php

I am dynamically creating variable to check the check boxes using loop. Actually the I am creating variable using string that is combination of 1 & 0. viz..`1010101000110`. Its like this. My string length is 50.

```
$user_authorisation = fetch_table_user($uid, '1', '12');
for ($j = 0; $j <= 49; $j++) {
    if (substr($user_authorisation, $j, 1) == '1') {
        $user_authorisation_field_ . $j = 'checked="checked"';
    }
}
```

My error is: 
**Warning: substr() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\shadaab\user_auth.php on line 38**

Comment: so much easier to use an array()

Comment: Indeed, you're looking for the functionality of an **array**!

Comment: For array also I have to check substr means I have to use this function

Comment: no you wouldn't, just loop through the array, checking the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're right, the best solution is to simply use an array:

```
    for ($j = 0; $j <= 49; $j++)
        if (substr($user_authorisation, $j, 1) == '1')
            $user_authorisation_field[$j] = 'checked="checked"';
```

But, specifically your problem lies in how you concatinate your variable: `$user_authorisation_field_ . $j`

@Dong shows how to do it correctly in his answer.

The reason the concatination is incorrect is because you want to treat `"user_authorisation_field_"` as a string and combine it with a number, but you are unintentially using it as a variable `$user_authorisation_field_` which is `UNDEFINED`.  So what you're doing is basically evaluates as:

```
UNDEFINED . 0 = 'string';
UNDEFINED . 1 = 'string';
UNDEFINED . 2 = 'string';
```

etc.  Doesn't work.

Comment: It's customary to link directly to the other answer to which you're referring because they can change position.

Comment: Y its not correct way how I have concatenated. Can you please specify the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
${'user_authorisation_field_' . $j} = 'checked="checked"';
```

It's a better choice to use array!